# How to check the number of Javascript statements run?

Tags: javascript, browser

IE8 is giving me the not-uncommon *"A script on this page is causing your browser to run slowly"* warning.  Of course this only happens in IE and not in any other browser. I am using an [Infragistics jQuery grid control](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls/grid.aspx#Overview) that seems to be causing the warning.

On doing a little bit of research I learnt that while nearly every other browser displays the warning based on execution time (generally 5 or 10 secs), IE does it based on number of statements processed (5 million statements).

I want to be sure it is the grid control and not something else.  Is there a way I can see the number of statements processed, maybe using something like Firebug or the IE developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 has a profiler built in and it seems like no one knows it exists. IEBlog had a [nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) explaining the profiler's features when IE8 was in BETA.

Comment: Thanks, that article is just what I was looking for. I knew IE8 had an inbuilt profile but I didn't know how to use it properly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE8 hit the F12 key and you will get a javascript debugger, step through the code and find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug or chrome dev tools, you can see the timeline of execution.